# Do these two nested loops really have the same quadratic time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Here is a segment of an algorithm I came up with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
   for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
      (...)
```

I am using this "double loop" to test all possible 2-element sums in a an array of size n.

Apparently (and I have to agree with it), this "double loop" is `O(n²)`:

```
n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = sum from 1 to n = (n (n - 1))/2
```

Here is where I am confused:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      (...)
```

This second "double loop" also has a complexity of `O(n²)`, when it is clearly (at worst) much (?) better than the first.

What am I missing? Is the information accurate? Can someone explain this "phenomenon"?

Comment: See related question http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/222895/complexity-in-nested-loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(n (n - 1))/2` simplifies to `n²/2 - n/2`. If you use really large numbers for `n`, the growth rate of `n/2` will be dwarfed in comparison to `n²`, so for the sake of calculating Big-O complexity, you effectively ignore it. Likewise, the "constant" value of 1/2 doesn't grow at all as `n` increases, so you ignore that too. That just leaves you with `n²`.

Just remember that complexity calculations are not the same as "speed". One algorithm can be five thousand times slower than another and still have a smaller Big-O complexity. But as you increase `n` to really large numbers, general patterns emerge that can typically be classified using simple formulae: `1`, `log n`, `n`, `n log n`, `n²`, etc.

It sometimes helps to create a graph and see what kind of line appears:

[image: y=x²]
[image: y=(x² - x)/2]

Even though the zoom factors of these two graphs are very different, you can see that the type of curve it produces is almost exactly the same.

Comment: So basically, I would have no reason of using the first `n^2 - n/2` algorithm over the second `n^2` one? (Since they are asymptotically identical)

Comment: @Werner: I added some more information to my answer. While the two are asymptotically identical, that doesn't mean that there is no difference in speed: it just means that as you get larger numbers the difference in speed is less likely to matter: say the first one takes 1,000,000 seconds to run, and the second one only takes 499,500 seconds. The second algorithm will be twice as fast, but how many people are willing to wait 5 days for their program to run, who wouldn't be willing to wait 10 days? To know which algorithm to use in practice, you need more information than the Big-O number.

Comment: I'd have to argue that, given the choice, no one would wait x time, when they have the option of only waiting ~x/2 time... So big-O would not be a useful figure in helping me decide which of these 2 algorithms to use? It would only be of use for algorithms of "drastically" different Os (O(n) vs O(n^2)) for instance...?

Comment: @Werner: I, for one, don't care if I have to wait 10 microseconds instead of 5 microseconds to get the information I need. Both of those options are fast enough. Likewise, waiting 5 days is too long, even if the alternative was waiting 10 days. (Ten seconds is usually too long for me!) Big-O is useful because it helps identify algorithms that will be asymptotically faster on large datasets where it's more likely to matter. If there's no Big-O difference, one algorithm may still be much faster, but it's less likely to matter: either find me something that'll run in <100ms or don't bother.

Comment: @Werner: So in this case, Big-O is only useful to the extent that it tells you both of these algorithms are going to be horrifically slow if N gets very high. If you want to know which one is really faster, you'll most likely need to test them both on real datasets. But that's a generally good rule of thumb, anyway: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Answer (score 2):

Constant factors.

Big-O notation ignores constant factors, so even though the second loop is slower by a constant factor, they end up with the same time complexity.

Right there in [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) it tells you that you can pick any old constant factor:

> ... if and only if there is a positive constant M ...

This is because we want to analyse the growth rate of an algorithm - constant factors just complicates things and are often system-dependent (operations may vary in duration on different machines).

You *could* just count certain types of operations, but then the question becomes which operation to pick, and what if that operation isn't predominant in some algorithm. Then you'll need to relate operations to each other (in a system-independent way, which is probably impossible), or you could just assign the same weight to each, but that would be fairly inaccurate as some operations would take significantly longer than others.

And how useful would saying `O(15n² + 568n + 8 log n + 23 sqrt(n) + 17)` (for example) really be? As opposed to just `O(n²)`.

---

(For the purpose of the below, assume `n >= 2`)

Note that we actually have asymptotically smaller (i.e. smaller as we approach infinity) terms here, but we can always simplify that to a matter of constant factors. ([It's `n(n+1)/2`, not `n(n-1)/2`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B2%2B3%2B...%2Bn))

```
n(n+1)/2 = n²/2 + n/2
       and
n²/2 <= n²/2 + n/2 <= n²
```

Given that we've just shown that `n(n+1)/2` lies between `C.n²` and `D.n²`, for two constants `C` and `D`, we've also just shown that it's `O(n²)`.

Note - big-O notation is actually strictly an upper bound (so we only care that it's smaller than a function, not between two), but it's often used to mean `Θ` (big-Theta), which cares about both bounds.

Comment: @Paul I can be simplified to a difference in constant factors. Asymptotically `n² - n < 2n²`.

Answer (score 0):

From [The Big O page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

> In typical usage, the formal definition of O notation is not used
>   directly; rather, the O notation for a function f is derived by the
>   following simplification rules:
>   If f(x) is a sum of several terms, the
>   one with the largest growth rate is kept, and all others omitted

Big-O is used only to give the asymptotic behaviour - that one is a bit faster than the other doesn't come into it - they're both O(N^2)

Answer (score 0):

You could also say that the first loop is O(n(n-1)/2). The fancy mathematical definition of big-O is something like:

function "f" is big-O of function "g" if there exists constants c, n such that f(x) < c*g(x) for some c and all x > n.

It's a fancy way of saying g is an upper bound past some point with some constant applied. It then follows that O(n(n-1)/2) = O((n^2-n)/2) is big-O of O(n^2), which is neater for quick analysis.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, your second code snippet

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) <-- this loop goes for n times
     for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) <-- loop also goes for n times
          (...)
```

So essentially, it's getting a `O(n*n) = O(n^2)` time complexity.

Per BIG-O theory, constant factor is neglected and only higher order is considered. that's to say, if complexity is `O(n^2+k)` then actual complexity will be `O(n^2)` constant `k` will be ignored.

(OR) if complexity is `O(n^2+n)` then actual complexity will be `O(n^2)` lower order `n` will be ignored.

So in your first case where complexity is `O(n(n - 1)/2)` will/can be simplified to

```
O(n^2/2 - n/2) = O(n^2/2) (Ignoring the lower order n/2)
= O(1/2 * n^2)
= O(n^2) (Ignoring the constant factor 1/2)
```